# FastAPI server running inside Docker container: Failed to connect to localhost port 8383 after 0 ms: Connection refused

Tags: docker, nginx, fastapi

I have a containerized FastAPI server that I'm trying to spin up on an EC2 instance. The container starts up fine and I see the server is running:

```
INFO:     Started server process [7]
INFO:     Waiting for application startup.
INFO:     Application startup complete.
INFO:     Uvicorn running on http://0.0.0.0:8383 (Press CTRL+C to quit)
```

I am also able to ssh into the running instance, and can successfully curl the root page (`http://localhost:8383`). However, curl-ing the same endpoint (http://localhost:8383) from the host results in the `Failed to connect to localhost port 8383 after 0 ms: Connection refused` error. This would seem to me like the container is not actually exposing the port, but I've `docker inspect`ed the container and it lists that the port is exposed:

```json
[
    {
        "Id": "b33deb28c5fce8ac52bf16aaa0b6037e2ff4124a99a990e1fe3b3d754cef6d98",
        "Created": "2022-12-26T05:52:07.64024483Z",
        "Path": "/bin/sh",
        "Args": [
            "-c",
            "uvicorn --proxy-headers --port ${PORT} --host 0.0.0.0 app.main:app"
        ],
        "State": {
            "Status": "running",
            "Running": true,
            "Paused": false,
            "Restarting": false,
            "OOMKilled": false,
            "Dead": false,
            "Pid": 4269,
            "ExitCode": 0,
            "Error": "",
            "StartedAt": "2022-12-26T05:52:08.146104473Z",
            "FinishedAt": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z"
        },
        "Image": "sha256:e566997f3a37510422d9b8d0a1f8ae029908acef739a7698cc9a4f96cbb78e39",
        "ResolvConfPath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/b33deb28c5fce8ac52bf16aaa0b6037e2ff4124a99a990e1fe3b3d754cef6d98/resolv.conf",
        "HostnamePath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/b33deb28c5fce8ac52bf16aaa0b6037e2ff4124a99a990e1fe3b3d754cef6d98/hostname",
        "HostsPath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/b33deb28c5fce8ac52bf16aaa0b6037e2ff4124a99a990e1fe3b3d754cef6d98/hosts",
        "LogPath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/b33deb28c5fce8ac52bf16aaa0b6037e2ff4124a99a990e1fe3b3d754cef6d98/b33deb28c5fce8ac52bf16aaa0b6037e2ff4124a99a990e1fe3b3d754cef6d98-json.log",
        "Name": "/great_wilbur",
        "RestartCount": 0,
        "Driver": "overlay2",
        "Platform": "linux",
        "MountLabel": "",
        "ProcessLabel": "",
        "AppArmorProfile": "",
        "ExecIDs": null,
        "HostConfig": {
            "Binds": null,
            "ContainerIDFile": "",
            "LogConfig": {
                "Type": "json-file",
                "Config": {}
            },
            "NetworkMode": "default",
            "PortBindings": {},
            "RestartPolicy": {
                "Name": "no",
                "MaximumRetryCount": 0
            },
            "AutoRemove": true,
            "VolumeDriver": "",
            "VolumesFrom": null,
            "CapAdd": null,
            "CapDrop": null,
            "CgroupnsMode": "host",
            "Dns": [],
            "DnsOptions": [],
            "DnsSearch": [],
            "ExtraHosts": null,
            "GroupAdd": null,
            "IpcMode": "private",
            "Cgroup": "",
            "Links": null,
            "OomScoreAdj": 0,
            "PidMode": "",
            "Privileged": false,
            "PublishAllPorts": false,
            "ReadonlyRootfs": false,
            "SecurityOpt": null,
            "UTSMode": "",
            "UsernsMode": "",
            "ShmSize": 67108864,
            "Runtime": "runc",
            "ConsoleSize": [
                0,
                0
            ],
            "Isolation": "",
            "CpuShares": 0,
            "Memory": 0,
            "NanoCpus": 0,
            "CgroupParent": "",
            "BlkioWeight": 0,
            "BlkioWeightDevice": [],
            "BlkioDeviceReadBps": null,
            "BlkioDeviceWriteBps": null,
            "BlkioDeviceReadIOps": null,
            "BlkioDeviceWriteIOps": null,
            "CpuPeriod": 0,
            "CpuQuota": 0,
            "CpuRealtimePeriod": 0,
            "CpuRealtimeRuntime": 0,
            "CpusetCpus": "",
            "CpusetMems": "",
            "Devices": [],
            "DeviceCgroupRules": null,
            "DeviceRequests": null,
            "KernelMemory": 0,
            "KernelMemoryTCP": 0,
            "MemoryReservation": 0,
            "MemorySwap": 0,
            "MemorySwappiness": null,
            "OomKillDisable": false,
            "PidsLimit": null,
            "Ulimits": [
                {
                    "Name": "nofile",
                    "Hard": 65536,
                    "Soft": 32768
                }
            ],
            "CpuCount": 0,
            "CpuPercent": 0,
            "IOMaximumIOps": 0,
            "IOMaximumBandwidth": 0,
            "MaskedPaths": [
                "/proc/asound",
                "/proc/acpi",
                "/proc/kcore",
                "/proc/keys",
                "/proc/latency_stats",
                "/proc/timer_list",
                "/proc/timer_stats",
                "/proc/sched_debug",
                "/proc/scsi",
                "/sys/firmware"
            ],
            "ReadonlyPaths": [
                "/proc/bus",
                "/proc/fs",
                "/proc/irq",
                "/proc/sys",
                "/proc/sysrq-trigger"
            ]
        },
        "GraphDriver": {
            "Data": {
                "LowerDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/684aa2a9d91eb41d5ccf26ef5515a989a1909d50bbba355b7dca3bc802d49d95-init/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/437dd322c1bf7514439ed292f206668ac2ef9bc32d547a83fea117de1b8891cd/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/33ecdfbef40d3b64accdbb7f1afeb34f388d02ea3112c199e5ccbd5d2c1c0c20/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/fffd586b2f98b234d41316049b0c2aa913c8ecd5a57b7a2211713642e843bdcf/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/4cc3a93536b947370eece5d8ac70e4cbd8acd638afb755affe8f2e01fa54e963/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/fd3d745ac50f60030e2e31b68af2b82c756c827f4b49e2494eedcde0ddd128ab/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/33503f91ec320f8c59608f126ad3a989c42a1381caa70d3064de6dcf12efdfac/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/eb27f4d7a55facde479cdc9af26888718e5bd4a7b1d91fa63a764e1d1e20bb1b/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/381ce07905d9c327bcbfb6f0d88749a0302e345437d2f9bdccae54fb71e7f6a7/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/29f0b55df9fb5b24a59c06607a68a50166365f5642695891000dd97f20516a1d/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/d18099aa9e5adf9bb6df28caa0abe604d44dabe0f31eb2c295c0b2dc0f75fd6e/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/7b38671006ea070a4fcb97484b7c21c20fa39b023086bec65dc268a469f629a7/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/f32dd15abece1ab3fabec84297fea1079f6f91b08362a0d222a61e7c50321615/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/a8f5689625f0d78f13f5c3cd657f7a04a502c3e47f0cff4587e7dcc8668ff747/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/6b4fa824255789e5d44343ea5bcf90862fe39af967d643f9f2168c4f23917210/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/2a3fa1727233ff7745d6e6c8dc7a0ddffa512cb32f96d8d7fa622df6701e7931/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/8fbcc58834bb2f1c5bc1985cf9aabd225207b9033b90c3d703c8c4a87fd5a16e/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/b367ef9dfbe273846d6c8f407c0ccea8cb285d5435dc1fae3f7f85857fa0706c/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/8d3b3ecf1826b2c141b66fb0e32a35ba3270d54dc88df38175dabe63d2830e46/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/548ae9d6f5ebf520b188095efe2cb919f27a0426b32c143e5f586405fb0664b4/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/35075f5f806338f0bc0e7edeaa2685258d5f4b16414842975b020e163f370742/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/371e969fdbc6704d286937e954702bf73b7c915af9976ebdc31e271c2f3d78b6/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/76968331d384e901ee3a3f16cc93a5ce3bd436f7dc03f6fc1e8f29ef495a1d84/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/a9e99d5ffe2d4afeb344cdb14dcf643c854594778350c4cf616673644e3df17b/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/15232d7ec0afec6b908daafa53883948a1724ba0d61b01fc37746487d503bc57/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/514dfee88f42cd6d1d238200b0a320ee3d67ddd7ff3eebda91db2d378f06f8b4/diff",
                "MergedDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/684aa2a9d91eb41d5ccf26ef5515a989a1909d50bbba355b7dca3bc802d49d95/merged",
                "UpperDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/684aa2a9d91eb41d5ccf26ef5515a989a1909d50bbba355b7dca3bc802d49d95/diff",
                "WorkDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/684aa2a9d91eb41d5ccf26ef5515a989a1909d50bbba355b7dca3bc802d49d95/work"
            },
            "Name": "overlay2"
        },
        "Mounts": [],
        "Config": {
            "Hostname": "b33deb28c5fc",
            "Domainname": "",
            "User": "",
            "AttachStdin": false,
            "AttachStdout": true,
            "AttachStderr": true,
            "ExposedPorts": {
                "8383/tcp": {}
            },
            "Tty": false,
            "OpenStdin": false,
            "StdinOnce": false,
            "Env": [
                "PORT=8383",
                "API_KEY=113631f4-d72a-4290-ba9e-f62a566fa689",
                "PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin",
                "LANG=C.UTF-8",
                "GPG_KEY=E3FF2839C048B25C084DEBE9B26995E310250568",
                "PYTHON_VERSION=3.9.16",
                "PYTHON_PIP_VERSION=22.0.4",
                "PYTHON_SETUPTOOLS_VERSION=58.1.0",
                "PYTHON_GET_PIP_URL=https://github.com/pypa/get-pip/raw/66030fa03382b4914d4c4d0896961a0bdeeeb274/public/get-pip.py",
                "PYTHON_GET_PIP_SHA256=1e501cf004eac1b7eb1f97266d28f995ae835d30250bec7f8850562703067dc6"
            ],
            "Cmd": [
                "/bin/sh",
                "-c",
                "uvicorn --proxy-headers --port ${PORT} --host 0.0.0.0 app.main:app"
            ],
            "Image": "<my-image>:<version>",
            "Volumes": null,
            "WorkingDir": "/app",
            "Entrypoint": null,
            "OnBuild": null,
            "Labels": {}
        },
        "NetworkSettings": {
            "Bridge": "",
            "SandboxID": "ae7182ddcb5da4667f5964337e7d8c8b63b9eb90d3852c17bcba50f22aa79b8e",
            "HairpinMode": false,
            "LinkLocalIPv6Address": "",
            "LinkLocalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
            "Ports": {
                "8383/tcp": null
            },
            "SandboxKey": "/var/run/docker/netns/ae7182ddcb5d",
            "SecondaryIPAddresses": null,
            "SecondaryIPv6Addresses": null,
            "EndpointID": "6bbf108cedee5f05ae30b9f3bf98b49a30252c1829b118024993f99242c0d64b",
            "Gateway": "172.17.0.1",
            "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
            "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
            "IPAddress": "172.17.0.2",
            "IPPrefixLen": 16,
            "IPv6Gateway": "",
            "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:11:00:02",
            "Networks": {
                "bridge": {
                    "IPAMConfig": null,
                    "Links": null,
                    "Aliases": null,
                    "NetworkID": "ec570411e1b31a214509d625551344fe7534e1c3eddd6cb349ff75249bbd1822",
                    "EndpointID": "6bbf108cedee5f05ae30b9f3bf98b49a30252c1829b118024993f99242c0d64b",
                    "Gateway": "172.17.0.1",
                    "IPAddress": "172.17.0.2",
                    "IPPrefixLen": 16,
                    "IPv6Gateway": "",
                    "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
                    "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
                    "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:11:00:02",
                    "DriverOpts": null
                }
            }
        }
    }
]
```

### Components:

- Docker container for server application (FastAPI)
- Nginx reverse proxy
- letsencrypt for https
- instance created via: `docker run --rm --expose 8383 <my-image>`

#### Dockerfile

```yaml
FROM python:3.9

WORKDIR /app

# RUN commands installing dependencies

COPY . .

ARG PORT=8383
ENV PORT ${PORT}
EXPOSE ${PORT}

CMD uvicorn --proxy-headers --port ${PORT} --host 0.0.0.0 app.main:app
```

#### nginx conf

```
server {
  server_name mydomain.com;

  location / {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8383;
  }

    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}
server {
    if ($host = mydomain.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


  listen 80;

  server_name mydomain.com;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was using `expose` instead of `publish`:

```
docker run --rm -p 8383:8383 <image-name>
```